# Are records syntactic sugar for classes?

Tags: java, record, java-record

I recently discovered Java [records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395), and it was amazing to learn about their existence and purpose.

However, I began to wonder if they are essentially just classes behind the scenes.

Does this mean that during compilation, they get converted into an explicit class with final private fields, a public constructor, and the necessary getters?

Comment: To quote for [JEP 395: Records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395): _"Enhance the Java programming language with records, which are **classes** that act as transparent carriers for immutable data."_ (emphasis mine). In total JEP 395 mentions the words "class" 86 times and "classes" 63 times. Basically everything (except primitives) are classes in Java, so it shouldn't come as a surprise that records are as well.

Comment: [Java class vs. record](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+class+vs+record+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: It really depends on what exactly you mean by "syntactic sugar", most people don't have a good definition of what they actually mean by that. Records *are* classes, as Mark pointed out. But whether or not they are "just syntactic sugar for regular classes" is really hard to answer without a firm definition.

Comment: Given how record patterns ([JEP 440: Record Patterns](https://openjdk.org/jeps/440)) only work for records, I would say that records are _not_ just syntactic sugar for classes, as they offer features that are not available for "normal" classes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: It looks like it's still syntactic sugar. It looks like they enable it via: 1) All `Record`s inherit from a single common superclass (`java.lang.Record`). 2) They provide a function, `Class.getRecordComponents`, that checks if the thing in question is a `Record` (via `Class.isRecord`, though I'm fairly sure that's equivalent to just checking if the superclass is `java.lang.Record`, due to the restrictive nature of `Record`s), and if so, knows it can use reflection in a defined way to determine the components it can extract.

Comment: I suspect the unique features of `Record`s could be simulated by a user-defined class, so long as they directly inherited from `java.lang.Record` *and* adhered to all the other narrow requirements of `Record`s that enable that reflection to figure out how to unpack it. The special `Record` declaration syntax just does all that work for you.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Would the range of operations on records types be sufficiently constrained to allow the JVM to refrain from creating object instances in cases where it could track and pass data around via other means?  If so, that would seem like something much more significant than syntactic sugar.

Comment: @supercat: That's kind of a meaningless guideline? The JIT optimizer can *always* do stuff if it can determine the parameters of the scenario let it skip work (a la the C++ as-if rule). The limitations of `Record`s might make it easier for the compiler authors to do stuff, but as the answer indicates, under-the-hood, it's *just* a class with a specific design, the only thing that is unique is that inherits from `java.lang.Record` (which has no meaningful behaviors of its own, it's just recognized specially by serialization and record patterns).

Comment: If you drive that argument to the extreme then all programming languages are just syntactic sugar for assembler language (which is itself just syntactic sugar for machine code which is itself just syntactic sugar for bits in memory which is ...). That's why working with a vague/flexible definition of "syntactic sugar" is often pointless: you get to vacuously true statements. They aren *not wrong* but also don't tell you anything useful about the feature you're inspecting.

Comment: @JoachimSauer statements "X is syntactic sugar for Y" are usually only made when X and Y are both constructs in the same language. Lots of things thus aren't syntactic sugar because what they desugar to can't be expressed in the same language at all. Furthermore, there is typically an assumption that the transformation be essentially injective. Every possible `record` you could define maps uniquely to a subclass of `java.lang.Record`, and thus you could transform it back to the original `record` declaration (modulo whitespace etc.). Most other compiler transformations aren't injective.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Under the hood it will still create a class (that's derived from [`java.lang.Record`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html)).

You can try it out yourself:

```java
// test.java
record Test(int foo, String bar) {}
```

When you compile this with `javac test.java` and disassemble it again with `javap Test` you'll get this code:

```java
final class Test extends java.lang.Record {
  Test(int, java.lang.String);
  public final java.lang.String toString();
  public final int hashCode();
  public final boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
  public int foo();
  public java.lang.String bar();
}
```

Comment: What about at the machine code level?  If e.g. a function creates and returns a `Record` with particular fields values, without persisting any other reference to the object, and the caller retrieves the fields and discards all references to the object after having done so, would the JVM be able to generate machine code that avoids the creation and abandonment of the object instance?

Comment: Java does not concern itself with the machine code level, that's an implementation detail of the JVM. Obviously a `record` won't magically make use of some previously unused instruction on your CPU or access previously unaccessible registers or memory areas, they are in the end just a special kind of class. But defining whether a feature is "syntactic sugar" in Java by inspecting the machine code level is like asking how to build an Airplane by inspecting individual welding points with a raster electron microscope: You will find *something*, but you might be missing the entire point.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer more accurately, it is an implementation detail of the JLS.